# Office 365 - Excel decimal addition

Tags: excel

Using Version 1810 (Build 11001.20108) of Excel in Office 365. If I sum the combination of numbers below using =sum() I get the total below. The behaviour was unexpected but managed through rounding. Is this something that others can replicate and or is this just a feature of Excel calculations?

- 420.67
- 420.67
- 420.67
- -1,399.63
- 55
- Total -82.620000000000100000000000

Thanks,

Ashley.

Comment: Excel 2010 does it as well (but had to increase number of decimal places) - either `ROUND` the sum or reduce the number of decimal places displayed.

Comment: This is a common issue with floating point arithmetic because of the internally binary digit system of computers. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel.

Answer (score 0):

Excel calculates to 15 decimal places - you can use ROUND() or one of the variants of ROUND() to change this but generally it's not a problem.